# how to implement graphql with java with nebula graph like dgraph

Tags: graphql, nebula-graph, dgraph

I have a java project

I have a nebula graph to save all my information

I need to have graphql queries

I implement it but we need a dynamic schema

so we save our schema for any of dynamic entity types

for example

our users want to have dynamic datatypes that we implement and save in nebula graph

our users can save vertex as items

after that we need to have endpoint for query in our all vertex that saved by those data types

[image: graphql query like dgraph in nebula by java]

https://dgraph.io/docs/graphql/queries/search-filtering/

we need to post our request like this

how can we implement it better

we have a good cache of our datatypes in the java layer.

is there any suggestion for us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, there is no GraphQL support/parsing layer implementation for NebulaGraph.

For java connector, there are some abstraction layers there, could you take a look at them?

- https://github.com/nebula-contrib/graph-ocean
- https://github.com/nebula-contrib/ngbatis
- https://github.com/nebula-contrib/nebula-jdbc

Also, equivlant queries(towards graphql) could be composed, too to return complex things in OpenCypher.